# Как найти одинаковые вхождения в словаре?

Tags: c#, linq

У менять есть словарь `IDictionary<string, List<ProductModel>> productDictionary`
В `ProductModel` есть строковый массив `string[] codes`. 
Как найти в словаре все `ProductModel`, у которых есть одинаковые значения в массивах `codes`? Т.е. у одной сущности `codes = { '123', 1234'}`, и у другой `codes = { '12353453', 1234'}`. Вот такие мне надо найти. У них есть совпадения по значению `'1234'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эммм... Взять все ProductModel:

```
var productModels = productDictionary.Values.SelectMany(list => list);
```

Сждойнить последовательность саму с собой и взять те пары `ProductModel`, у которых пересечение подколлекций `codes` не пустое:

```
var res = productModels.Join(productModels, p1 => 1, p2 => 1, (p1, p2) => (p1, p2))
                       .Where(t => t.p1 != t.p2 && t.p1.codes.Intersect(t.p2.codes).Any());
```

На выходе получим кортеж из двух `ProductModel`.

Если у вас компилятор/фреймворк не самые свежие - придется вместо кортежа использовать анонимный класс (`new { p1, p2 }` вместо `(p1, p2)`)

Тут минус - будут получены пары (x, y) и (y, x) одновременно, чтобы их исключить придется переписать примерно так:

```
var productModels = productDictionary.Values.SelectMany(list => list).ToList();
var result = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, productModels.Count)
             from y in Enumerable.Range(x + 1, productModels.Count - x - 1)
             where productModels[x].codes.Intersect(productModels[y].codes).Any()
             select new { p1 = productModels[x], p2 = productModels[y] };
```

Здесь мы материализуем коллекцию и у нас появляется возможность обращаться по индексу, поэтому мы в первом "цикле" перебираем все значения `x` от `0` до `Count - 1`, а во втором все `y` от `x + 1` до `Count - 1`, это дает нам заведомо не повторяющиеся пары

Comment: Я к сожалению не силен в linq. И студия ругается на вторую строку

Comment: А если `(p1, p2) => (p1, p2)` переписать так: `(p1, p2) => new { p1, p2 }`?

Comment: t => t.p1 Cannot resolve symbol 'p1'

Comment: Уберите `[]`, там в комментарии опечатка была, я исправил

Comment: Оба варианта работают. Спасибо! Буду очень благодарен, если вкратце опишите тот код где исключили одну пару.

Comment: Дополнил, во втором варианте мы обращаемся по индексу, поэтому просто берем индексы такие, что всегда `x < y`, даже проверять `t.p1 != t.p2` поэтому не нужно

Answer (score 3):

Например, так:

```
var result = productDictionary
    .Values  // достаем перечень значений словаря
    .SelectMany(v => v)  // собираем их в плоский перечень ProductModel
    .Where(p => p.codes.Distinct().Count() != p.codes.Length)  // отбираем те ProductModel, у которых есть совпадения в codes
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Это работает. Но я наверно не много не правильно выразился. Найти все ProductModel, у которых есть одинаковые значения в codes. Т.е. у одной сущности codes = { '123', 1234'}, и у другой codes = { '12353453', 1234'}. Вот такие мне надо найти. У них есть совпадения по значению '1234'

Comment: @a.kond, ну блин... Мой ответ в первой редакции именно это и делал...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, возвращайте :)